# Very slow when inserting data into a MySQL 5.7 table using Java (Locks happened)

Tags: java, mysql, hikaricp, mysql-5.7

I recently migrated and upgraded my database from MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 5.7. Everything worked perfectly on the old server before. But now I found a glitch on my Java application that I use (on the old system) for inserting data into a table. Strangely, the query works fine if I execute it on the console.

```
INSERT INTO TMPALL 
SELECT U.PERNR, U.SEQUENCE, U.STARTDATE, U.ENDDATE, PERSONNELAREA, PERSONNELSUBAREA, EMPLOYEEGROUP, EMPLOYEESUBGROUP, NOMINALPOKOK, FULLNOMINALPOKOK, NOMINALPREMIUM, FULLNOMINALPREMIUM, IFNULL(AMOUNT, 0), IFNULL(FULLAMOUNT, 0), NOMINALPOKOK + NOMINALPREMIUM + IFNULL(AMOUNT, 0), FULLNOMINALPOKOK + FULLNOMINALPREMIUM + IFNULL(FULLAMOUNT, 0) 
FROM TMPJOINUP U 
LEFT JOIN TMPJOINJG J 
ON U.PERNR = J.PERNR 
AND U.STARTDATE BETWEEN J.STARTDATE AND J.ENDDATE 
AND U.ENDDATE BETWEEN J.STARTDATE AND J.ENDDATE
```

This query, if it's executed using Java app (I built it using mysql-connector-java-5.1.40 and HikariCP-2.5.1), it will take 5000+ seconds to have result of 193,085 rows. But if I execute it in MySQL client console, it will only take 5 secs. 
Also all other queries to the server, from MySQL clients, PHP apps and Java apps, running fine.
Is anyone able to advise me on this situation?

This is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `TMPALL` (
  `PERNR` varchar(8) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SEQUENCE` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `STARTDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENDDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONNELAREA` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONNELSUBAREA` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMPLOYEEGROUP` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMPLOYEESUBGROUP` varchar(2) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOMINALPOKOK` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FULLNOMINALPOKOK` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOMINALPREMIUM` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FULLNOMINALPREMIUM` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOMINALJG` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FULLNOMINALJG` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOMINALCOMBINED` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FULLNOMINALCOMBINED` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci 

CREATE TABLE `TMPJOINUP` (
  `PERNR` varchar(8) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SEQUENCE` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `STARTDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENDDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONNELAREA` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONNELSUBAREA` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMPLOYEEGROUP` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMPLOYEESUBGROUP` varchar(2) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `POKOK` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOMINALPOKOK` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FULLNOMINALPOKOK` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PREMIUM` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOMINALPREMIUM` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FULLNOMINALPREMIUM` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOMINALCOMBINED` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FULLNOMINALCOMBINED` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `IDX1` (`PERNR`,`STARTDATE`,`ENDDATE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci

CREATE TABLE `TMPJG` (
  `PERNR` varchar(8) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SEQUENCE` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `STARTDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENDDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `WAGETYPE` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AMOUNT` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FULLAMOUNT` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `IDX1` (`PERNR`,`STARTDATE`,`ENDDATE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

And lastly, I got this when execute `show engine innodb status;`

```
---TRANSACTION 853444993, ACTIVE 3279 sec
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
1302 lock struct(s), heap size 155856, 272621 row lock(s), undo log entries 74324
MySQL thread id 428981, OS thread handle 139794084808448, query id 5078166 localhost 127.0.0.1 root Sending data
INSERT INTO TMPALL SELECT U.PERNR, U.SEQUENCE, U.STARTDATE, U.ENDDATE, PERSONNELAREA, PERSONNELSUBAREA, EMPLOYEEGROUP, EMPLOYEESUBGROUP, NOMINALPOKOK, FULLNOMINALPOKOK, NOMINALPREMIUM, FULLNOMINALPREMIUM, IFNULL(AMOUNT, 0), IFNULL(FULLAMOUNT, 0), NOMINALPOKOK + NOMINALPREMIUM + IFNULL(AMOUNT, 0), FULLNOMINALPOKOK + FULLNOMINALPREM
```

I figure there's some locks found when executed by Java, but it's running normal on MySQL client.

Comment: can you try without `ENGINE=InnoDB` ?

Comment: When inserting large data sets, try doing `LOCK TABLE TMPALL WRITE`, and when done `UNLOCK TABLES`